# NIC recommendation and advice for building network packet capture PC

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcpip, capture

Greetings,

I am trying to build a dedicated PC for capturing and recording network packets in a heavily loaded test environment. I am expecting total data loads to be between **150-200Mbps** and want to achieve 0 packet loss with tcpdump over **10-20 minute capture intervals**.

The capture PC shall be configured with **Ubuntu** running **tcpdump**. The packets are mirrored to a single port on my **HP ProCurve 1810g switch** and then onward to the capture PC.

What NIC chipset to use (or avoid) would be helpful, along with any other considerations that would influence packet loss in the scenario I have described.

**What are the key performance factors I should be considering in building such a dedicated packet recorder?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best information I have found so far on getting the most out of commodity PC hardware.

http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/

The combination of gulp and tcpdump should provide adequate support for my needs with low-cost hardware :-)

The manual page for gulp can be found at: http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/gulpman.html

Anybody else got any ideas or advice on this?